# Angularjs ng-repeat is not refreshing with updated values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a functionality to insert and update records on popup (ngdialog). When Im adding and updating records are inserting and updating in the database but those updated values are not binding using ng-repeat.

Updated records are showing only when I refresh the complete page.

Controller code :

```
 $scope.OpenUserPlaceMap = function (userplace) {
    if (angular.isObject(userplace)) {
        $scope.UserPlaceID = userplace.Id;
        $scope.UserPlaceName = userplace.Name;
        $scope.FormattedAddress = userplace.FormattedAddress;
    }
    else {
        $scope.UserPlaceID = '';
        $scope.UserPlaceName = '';
        $scope.FormattedAddress = '';
    }
    ngDialogAlert.ShowPopup('UserPlacesMap.html', 'CommanCtrl', $scope);
};

$scope.SubmitUserPlace = function (flg) {
    $scope.error = [];

    var UserPlace = {
        "Id": $scope.UserPlaceID,
        "UserId": $scope.UserId,
        "Name": $scope.UserPlaceName,
        "FormattedAddress": $scope.FormattedAddress,
        "CircleID": $scope.DefaultCircle,
        "Latitude": $scope.Latitude,
        "Logitude": $scope.Logitude,
        "Flag": flg
    };
    SWT360Service.InUpdDelUserPlace(UserPlace).success(function (data) {
        if (data > 0) {

            ngDialogAlert.ClosePopup();
            $scope.error.push('Saved Successfully');
            ngDialogAlert.ShowAlert(true, $scope.error);
            $scope.LoadUserPlaces();
        }
        else {
            $scope.error.push('User Place not saved Successfully !');
        }
    }).error(function (data) {
        $scope.error.push(data);
    });
}
 $scope.LoadUserPlaces = function () {
    $scope.UserPlaces = '';
    SWT360Service.GetUserPlace(null, $scope.UserId, $scope.DefaultCircle).success(function (data) {
            $scope.UserPlaces = data;
    });
};
```

View:

```
 <div class="container" ng-repeat="place in UserPlaces" style="cursor:pointer;" ng-click="OpenUserPlaceMap(place);">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 bg-success text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <span style="display:none;">{{place.id}}</span> <span>{{place.Name}}</span> <br />
                        <span>{{place.FormattedAddress}}</span><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a watcher on `UserPlaces` like below and wrap everything inside it. $watch watches and update scope.

```html
$scope.OpenUserPlaceMap = function (userplace) {
    if (angular.isObject(userplace)) {
        $scope.UserPlaceID = userplace.Id;
        $scope.UserPlaceName = userplace.Name;
        $scope.FormattedAddress = userplace.FormattedAddress;
    }
    else {
        $scope.UserPlaceID = '';
        $scope.UserPlaceName = '';
        $scope.FormattedAddress = '';
    }
    ngDialogAlert.ShowPopup('UserPlacesMap.html', 'CommanCtrl', $scope);
};

$scope.$watch('UserPlaces', function(UserPlaces) {

    $scope.SubmitUserPlace = function (flg) {
        $scope.error = [];

        var UserPlace = {
            "Id": $scope.UserPlaceID,
            "UserId": $scope.UserId,
            "Name": $scope.UserPlaceName,
            "FormattedAddress": $scope.FormattedAddress,
            "CircleID": $scope.DefaultCircle,
            "Latitude": $scope.Latitude,
            "Logitude": $scope.Logitude,
            "Flag": flg
        };
        SWT360Service.InUpdDelUserPlace(UserPlace).success(function (data) {
            if (data > 0) {

                ngDialogAlert.ClosePopup();
                $scope.error.push('Saved Successfully');
                ngDialogAlert.ShowAlert(true, $scope.error);
                $scope.LoadUserPlaces();
            } else {
                $scope.error.push('User Place not saved Successfully !');
            }
        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error.push(data);
      });
    }
    $scope.LoadUserPlaces = function () {
        $scope.UserPlaces = '';
        SWT360Service.GetUserPlace(null, $scope.UserId, $scope.DefaultCircle).success(function (data) {
            $scope.UserPlaces = data;
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Anand thanks for reply. Im getting the updated records in Userplaces object but ng-repeat is not refreshing after binding.